# Sharepoint Master list, with views seperated across a site - SP 2010

Tags: 2010, list, site

I have a bit of an issue I'd like some input on.

I'm creating a "Master List", with a bunch of different views for different business units in my company.

My original idea was to have a main site, with the master list on it, then subsites that have views of this list, dedicated for different business units.

The idea of this was so that when other business units adds/changes items, the master list will also be updated, as they are the same list just a different view.

**So here's my issues:**

1. This list won't be able to be locked down as it is only views right? This isn't the biggest deal, just means that data can be accessed if someone tries to view another business unit's view.
2. how do I actually separate the list onto subsites? My idea was to add an "Existing list" but apparently my master list doesn't appear as an option on my subsite.

Adding links on the subsites to the main site is an option.. but I'm trying to basically take a secluded view ie. "Finance View" and put it on it's own site so that it's secluded there.

If I can't actually solve this issue, my best bet is to store everything all on one site? with separate areas for the different views? this would mean that data could be seen by different people surely..

Appreciate the help guys

Answer (score 0):

The List View Web Part can be saved from the parent site as either a file or directly to the Web Part gallery. After that the web part can be added to the sub site.

Please follow steps mentioned in below given link.

[Show listview webpart from parent site on subsite in same site collection](http://sharepointontop.blogspot.com/2012/06/show-listview-webpart-from-parent-site.html)